# jQuery dialog box does not pop up

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dialog box that is supposed to pop up if the user is not logged in, and presses the "vote up" link on this page: http://www.problemio.com

I have some JavaScript here: [problemio.com/js/problemio.js](http://problemio.com/js/problemio.js) and I declare that popup in the global variables like this:

```
var $dialog = $('#loginpopup')
    .dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        title: 'Login Dialog'
    }); 

var $problemId = $('#theProblemId', '#loginpopup');

$("#newprofile").click(function () 
{
    $("#login_div").hide();
    $("#newprofileform").show();
});
```

but not exactly sure if the `#newprofile` code is right, or how to make it global, or whether it can't be global.  This confusion stems from me being kind of new at this.

The JavaScript console in Chrome does not show any errors relevant to this, which is even more confusing.

Any ideas on what I might be doing wrong?

Thanks!!

Comment: try:   if ( queue.login == null)

Comment: @zdrsh that check isn't the problem.  The code gets to the $dialog.open line, but it just doesn't open anything.

Comment: i'm working on chrome and it doesn't. i'll try firefox

Comment: @zdrsh for me it works on chrome.  Look, I'll add alert statements in the if block

Comment: @zdrsh actually there was already an alert statement in that block which works.  Did you press the "vote up" link?  I did make the change you suggested, but it still doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using

$("#loginpopup").dialog();

> A call to
>
> ```
> $(foo).dialog()
> ```
>
> will initialize a dialog instance and will auto-open the dialog by
>   default. If you want to reuse a dialog, the easiest way is to disable
>   the "auto-open" option with:
>
> ```
> $(foo).dialog({ autoOpen: false })
> ```
>
> and open it with
>
> ```
> $(foo).dialog('open')
> ```
>
> . To close it, use
>
> ```
> $(foo).dialog('close')
> ```

[jQuery UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/)

Comment: that worked!!  Why do you think the original way didn't work? I think it was legit in the API.  Thanks!!

Comment: i am not sure. the original works fine for $dialog.dialog("close"); $("#loginpopup") is only a reference to the DOM element, $dialog is a reference for the jQuery Dialog.. But i expected $("#loginpopup").dialog("open"); to be the correct syntax..

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit confused, not sure if your question is complete. However, you have `autoOpen: false` set on the dialog, so you have to manually open it with:

```
$("#loginpopup").dialog("open");
```

in your "vote up" click handler.

Comment: yeah I thought that this code opens it: $dialog.dialog('open');  It used to open it before I did some reshuffling.  I didn't post all my code, but I did post a link to where all that JavaScript code is so you can see how it is.